# Trouble in Delete Multiple Documents by one Query in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, bulk-delete

I am trying to delete multiple documents from one types at a time,
this is my code.

```
var ids = new List<Int64> { 1, 2, 3 };
            var bulkResponse = Client.DeleteMany<Demo>(ids.Select(x => new Demo { EmpId = x }));
```

while i am executing this code the code will run fine but it doesn't do any effect in elasticsearch database.

It is showing following message while debugging (in watch window) :
**{Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful low level call on POST: /_bulk}  Nest.IBulkResponse {Nest.BulkResponse}**

Comment: May you share `bulkResponse.DebugInformation`?

Comment: here it is,
"Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful low level call on POST"

Comment: Hmm ... I was expecting to see a little bit more information. Is there anything else in `bulkResponse.ServerError`?

Comment: nope ! 
bulkResponse.ServerError is null bro

Comment: Can you capture the request and response with Fiddler: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/logging-with-fiddler.html and add it to your question please?

Comment: i am not aware with this Fiddler concept @RussCam